# Understanding seq_len in R

Tags: r

Im new to coding and using r and have 2 questions about `seq_len(n)`.
My first question is that in one of my lecture notes we were told to use `seq_len(n)` instead of 1:n because it helps in the situation for n=0. When creating a loop to calculate the factorial using `seq_len(n)` instead of 1:n resulted in `n=0` being 1 for 0! I don't understand why this works.

For my second question, I created a function for double factorial and in my equation I used the formula `prod(2*seq_len(n/2))` and I noticed that regardless of what the integer beside `seq_len(0)` is the `prod()` function gives an output of 1 which does not make sense to me since `seq_len(0)` gives a `numeric(0)` and any number multiplied by 0 should be zero.

Comment: `numeric(0)` isn't `0`. It's a `numeric` vector of length 0. That is, an empty vector - `vector("numeric", length=0)` Looking at the help for `?prod` there is a note in the details that suggests `NULL` and `numeric(0)` values are essentially ignored and treated like `1`, because anything multiplied by 1 is just itself again.

Answer (score 7):

If `n = 0`, `1:n` would give:

```
> 1:0
[1] 1 0
>
```

It gives ranges, but if `n2` is smaller than `n1`, it get's treated as vector definitions, like:

```
> as.integer(c(1, 0))
[1] 1 0
>
```

Which isn't what we want, whereas `seq_len` gives:

```
> seq_len(0)
integer(0)
>
```

You might be wondering why is it an integer, but even for `seq_len` where `n` `>` `0`, it is a class of `integer`:

```
> class(seq_len(0))
[1] "integer"
> class(seq_len(100))
[1] "integer"
>
```

### Also `integer(0)` isn't `0`, it specified that the integer vector has `0` elements!!!

---

As in [RStudio documentation](https://rpubs.com/Mentors_Ubiqum/seq_len):

> The `seq_len(number)` function creates a sequence that starts at 1 and
> with steps of 1 finishes at the number value. A common use of this
> function is to create indexes that match the length of a vector in
> order to make plots.