# How to use lapply() to store results from simulations?

Tags: r, multithreading, random

I want to use mclapply and take advantage of multiple cores. But the below isn't working. I want to create a list with 100 simulations, each of size 50. any suggestions?

```
sim_holder <- vector("list", length=100)
lapply(sim_holder, rnorm, n=50)
```

Answer (score 4):

For `lapply` & Co, no initialization is needed. Use `set.seed()` to get reproducible results, but this has its pitfalls as you will get reproducible but sometimes different numbers depending on which method you use. In R, get used to using `seq_len(9)` instead of `1:9`, for example [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69640503/6574038).

`lapply` is straightforward. You need an anonymous function, use `i` (or sth else that is **not** used by FUN, i.e. `rnorm()` in this case) to iterate without need to use it in the function.

```
> set.seed(42)
> lapply(seq_len(2), FUN=\(i) rnorm(n=5))
[[1]]
[1]  1.3709584 -0.5646982  0.3631284  0.6328626  0.4042683

[[2]]
[1] -0.10612452  1.51152200 -0.09465904  2.01842371 -0.06271410
```

Using `replicate` might be more convenient, note that `replicate` also has an `n=` argument.

```
> set.seed(42)
> replicate(n=2, expr=rnorm(n=5), simplify=FALSE)
[[1]]
[1]  1.3709584 -0.5646982  0.3631284  0.6328626  0.4042683

[[2]]
[1] -0.10612452  1.51152200 -0.09465904  2.01842371 -0.06271410

> set.seed(42)
> replicate(2, {\(i) {rnorm(n=5)}}(), simplify=FALSE)
[[1]]
[1]  1.3709584 -0.5646982  0.3631284  0.6328626  0.4042683

[[2]]
[1] -0.10612452  1.51152200 -0.09465904  2.01842371 -0.06271410

> FN <- \(i) rnorm(n=5)
> set.seed(42)
> replicate(2, FN(), simplify=FALSE)
[[1]]
[1]  1.3709584 -0.5646982  0.3631284  0.6328626  0.4042683

[[2]]
[1] -0.10612452  1.51152200 -0.09465904  2.01842371 -0.06271410
```

**`parallel::mclapply`** is similar to `lapply`. For reproducibility we might want to use `RNGkind("L'Ecuyer-CMRG")` [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30469143/6574038) and in `mclapply` keep the default setting `mc.set.seed=TRUE`.

```
> RNGkind("L'Ecuyer-CMRG")
> set.seed(42)
> parallel::mclapply(seq_len(2), FUN=\(i) rnorm(n=5), mc.cores=7L)
[[1]]
[1]  1.11932846 -0.07617141 -0.35021912 -0.33491161 -1.73311280

[[2]]
[1] -0.2084809 -1.0341493 -0.2629060  0.3880115  0.8331067
```

Comment: Is there a bug in `lapply`? Comparing the results of the 1st form with the results of both the2nd and `replicate` there is a difference of 1 in the output list's first vector and of 2 in the second. The same goes for `parallel::mclapply`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Also wondered, but I think when not using anonymous function, `seq_len` is used as mean? Something's weird for sure!

Comment: Yes, that's it, good catch. And to set mean and sd `lapply(seq_len(2), FUN=rnorm, n=5, mean=0, sd=1)` throws an error `unused argument (X[[i]])`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Also noticed, it doesn't take `sd=1`, `mean=0` alone works.

Comment: But then `seq_len(2)` is passed on to `rnorm` as `sd`. The right way to output what the OP is expecting is `replicate`. Upvote, btw.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Tried `lapply(seq_len(2), FUN=runif, n=3)`?

Comment: **The issues on which we have commented can be found in [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77850067/revisions).**

Comment: @RuiBarradas The explanation for this behavior is: _"Function FUN must be able to accept as input any of the elements of X"_ (from `?lapply`), and when we use up all arguments of FUN like `lapply(X=seq_len(2), FUN=rnorm, n=5, mean=0, sd=1)`, X can no longer be accepted.

Comment: Thank you! My issue was thinking I had to initialize.

Comment: Note that default reproducibility in `parallel::mclapply` depends on using the same number of cores.  A workaround is to set `mc.preschedule = FALSE`, which can add some overhead with long vectors.

Answer (score 2):

For this application, there's no need for `x` to be a list, you just need to ensure that `x` is a vector or list that you can apply the function to - `lapply` will still return a list of the output. Here `x` can just be a vector repeating the `n` argument to `rnorm` (50), 100 times. It can be a list repeating 50 100 times too. Both lines below work.

```
output_list <- lapply(rep(50,100),rnorm)
output_list <- lapply(as.list(rep(50,100)),rnorm)
```